# Why does this SSIS expression evaluate to 10 hours ago on my server

Tags: sql, datetime, ssis

All,

I am terrible at undwerstanding time zones etc.

Can anyone help me understand why this:

> @[$Package::ExportFileLocation] + REPLACE( 
>   @[$Package::ExportFileName] + "_" +   SUBSTRING(REPLACE( (DT_STR, 50,
>   1250) GETDATE() , ":", "") , 1, 10)  , " ", "_")   + "."+ 
>   @[$Package::ExportFileExtension]

produces:

> C:\Users\russellm\Desktop\PWCCurrentCodeExtract_2014-08-13.TXT

on my local and this:

> C:\Users\russellm\Desktop\PWCCurrentCodeExtract_2014-08-12.TXT

on the server.

All the servers dates and time zones seen to be fine.

Here is the full SSIS expression.

thanks
Russ

Comment: Where is the full SSIS expression?

Comment: Can't you see it? 
@[$Package::ExportFileLocation] + REPLACE(  @[$Package::ExportFileName] + "_" +   SUBSTRING(REPLACE( (DT_STR, 50, 1250) GETDATE() , ":", "") , 1, 10)  , " ", "_")   + "."+  @[$Package::ExportFileExtension]

Comment: Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008+ (not sure about earlier) gets the current date/time from Windows, so if you say that the Server and your PC have the same time and zone settings, then perhaps your SQL Server Collations are different. This could mean that using Code Page 1250 to convert your date is having a different effect.

This page shows which CodePage should be used with a particular collation

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

FYI, most examples I have found use CP1252, so you might want to try using

```
@[$Package::ExportFileLocation] + REPLACE( @[$Package::ExportFileName] + "_" + SUBSTRING(REPLACE( (DT_STR, 50, 1252) GETDATE() , ":", "") , 1, 10) , " ", "_") + "."+ @[$Package::ExportFileExtension]
```

to see if that makes a difference.